# How did Bumblebee destroy Dropkick so easily?

Tags: plot-explanation, transformers, bumblebee

In *Bumblebee* (2018), Bumblebee grabs a chain and wraps it around Dropkick. Dropkick shows no fear to the chains.

> Dropkick: You think these little chains can hold...

But with one swift pull, Bumblebee tears Dropkick to pieces.

[image: Dropkick broken into pieces]

How did Bumblebee destroy Dropkick so easily?

Comment: Bee traps chain around dropkick, whie he wrap it around, he probably wrapped it around some weak points of dropkick. and on the pull, chain goes through those weak points, separates'em from his body. then boom! Since DK had no idea about Bee's plan, he can gloat

Answer (score 2):

Right before Bumblebee pulls the chains, theres a few seconds showing the chains tighten around key parts of Dropkicks body. You can see the chain fasten around key joints such as the knees, and shoulders. Bumblebee just had to pull hard enough for the chains to tighten and cut off those key joints and dropkick was no more.